# C++ comparing a pre-reserved hash map(std::unordered_map) with integer key and contiguous data array(std::vector)

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, unordered-map

Assume that using a **hash map** structure with `int` key type:

```
std::unordered_map<int, data_type> um;
```

Plus, when the total(or maximum) number of elements `N` is known, hash table can be constructed in advance.

```
um.reserve(N); // This will chainly call rehash() function...
```

Here, an integer itself can be used as an **identity(hash) function** for a hash table, as far as I know.

Meanwhile, for a **contiguous** data set(i.e. `std::vector`, or a simple array), it can be **random-accessed** by displacement from the address of front-most data.

Both containers use `int` as an accessing key, like this:

```
um[1] = data_type(1); //std::unordered_map<int, data_type>
v[1] = data_type(1); //std::vector<data_type>
```

Then, is there any difference between the constructed hash table and `std::vector`, in memory usage or in searching mechanism/performance, or in anything else?

Let's make the problem tangible.

If I know that 3 keys `0`,`5`, `9987` are certainly used, but keys `1`~`9986` may or may not be used.

If I know no key in the set would be bigger than `10000`, then using `std::vector` of size `10000` will guarantee O(1) time complexity for accessing random data, but memory would be wasted.

In this situation, does `std::unordered_map` produce a better solution for the problem?
*I mean, a solution that saves as much memory as possible while maintaining the time complexity in the same level.

Comment: Better by what metric?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Uh oh, I apologize. In this case, the best time complexity is already obtained by using `std::vector` of size=`10000`, but for the space complexity it's the worst. So, it would be "better" if the new solution distributes them about 7:3, since in my field memory is less important than speed. But I'm sure I would learn a lot from any new solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus, when the total(or maximum) number of elements N is known, hash table can be constructed in advance.

um.reserve(N); // This will chainly call rehash() function...

> Here, an integer itself can be used as an identity(hash) function for a hash table, as far as I know.

That's true, and reasonable in two very different scenarios: 1) when the values are pretty much contiguous with perhaps a few missing values, or 2) when the values are quite random.  In many other situations, you may risk excessive hash table collisions if you don't provide a meaningful hash function.

> Then, is there any difference between the constructed hash table and std::vector, in memory usage or in searching mechanism/performance, or in anything else?

Yes.  After your `.reserve(N)`, the hash table allocates a contiguous block of memory (basically, an array) for at least `N` "buckets".  If we consider the GCC implementation, N will be rounded up to a prime.  Each bucket *may* store an iterator into a forward-linked list of `pair<int, data_type>` nodes.

So, if you actually put N entries into the hash table, you have...

- an array of >= N elements of `sizeof(forward-list-iterator)` size
- N memory allocations of >= `sizeof(pair<int, data_type>) + sizeof(next-pointer/iterator for forward-list)`

...whilst the `vector` only uses about `N * sizeof(data_type)` bytes of memory: potentially a small fraction of the memory used by the hash table, and as all the vector's memory for `data_type`s is contiguous, you're much more likely to benefit from the CPU caching elements adjacent to one you're currently trying to access, such that they're all much faster to access later.

On the other hand, if you haven't put many elements into the hash table, then the main thing using memory is the array of buckets containing iterators, which are usually the size of pointers (e.g. 32 or 64 bits each), whereas the vector of `data_type` - if you `reserve(N)` there too - will already have allocated `N * sizeof(data_type)` bytes of memory - for large `data_type`s that may be massively more than the hash table.  Still, you can often allocate virtual memory, and if you haven't faulted the pages of memory in such that they need physical backing memory, there's no meaningful memory usage or performance penalty to your program or computer.  (At least with 64 bit programs, virtual address space is effectively  unlimited).

> If I know that 3 keys 0,5, 9987 are certainly used, but keys 1~9986 may or may not be used.

> If I know no key in the set would be bigger than 10000, then using std::vector of size 10000 will guarantee O(1) time complexity for accessing random data, but memory would be wasted.

> In this situation, does std::unordered_map produce a better solution for the problem? *I mean, a solution that saves as much memory as possible while maintaining the time complexity in the same level.

In this situation, if you `reversed(10000)` up front and the `data_type` was not significantly bigger than an iterator/pointer, then the `unordered_map` would be unequivocably worse in every regard.  If you don't reserve up front, the hash table would only allocate space for a handful of buckets, and you'd be using a lot less virtual address space than a `vector` with 10000 elements (even if `data_type` was `bool`).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is different.

An unordered_map has the concept of [buckets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/bucket/) -

> A bucket is a slot in the container's internal hash table to which elements are assigned based on the hash value of their key. Buckets are numbered from 0 to (bucket_count-1).

An unordered_map calculates hash value of the key which points to a bucket. The desired value is in that bucket. Now note that multiple keys can point to a single bucket. In your case it may even happen that `um[0]`,`um[5]` and `um[9987]` all lie in the same bucket! Search within bucket is linear in time.

> In this situation, does std::unordered_map produce a better solution for the problem?

In case you have sparse data, use an unordered_map but with an appropriate reserve (or no reserve at all and use the default allocation policy). There's no point if you do a `myMap.reserve(MAX_ELEMENTS)` since that will again just lead to memory wastage.

Else, use a vector. You get a guaranteed `O(1)` lookup. Since its linear its super cache-friendly. Whereas on an unordered_map you may get the worst case lookup of `O(N)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 3 elements to pack, the best solution is to use `std::vector<std::pair<int, data_type>>` :) It takes even less memory than `std::unordered_map<int, data_type>` (which actually allocates several vectors-buckets), and the lookup performance is also the best for small number of elements due to very small constants.

For larger maps, `O(1)` complexity is guaranteed by both `std::vector<data_type>`, and `std::unordered_map<int, data_type>`, but the constant hiding in `O` is much lower for the vector, since it doesn't need to check the element against other elements in the bucket. I would suggest to always prefer vector unless you lack memory to fit it, in which case you can save the memory using the `unordered_map` by sacrificing a bit of performance.